# FullCalendar.js get date range as string from select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar.js](https://fullcalendar.io/) to enable a user to select a single date or range of dates from a visual calendar [like this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting-demo).

[The documentation specifies](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) that I should implement the `select` function to capture the start date `startStr` and end date `endStr` of the user's selection.

Below is the code I thought would do this:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    selectable: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },
    defaultDate: today,
    navLinks: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: [],
    select: function(selectionInfo) {
       console.log(selectionInfo.startStr);
       console.log(selectionInfo.endStr);
    }
 });
```

**Output:**

```
undefined
undefined
```

Clearly my approach is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're reading the wrong version of the documentation. Your code above looks like version 3 of fullCalendar. That documentation is for version 4. In the top right corner of the documentation page you'll see a little drop-down list saying v4. Open it and change to v3. Or click here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/select-callback . The two versions are very different in a lot of ways so make sure you always study the correct set of docs.

Comment: Ah, astute observation! Rather than delete the question, I will leave it open as I have found an alternative solution which will most likely help others.

Comment: Start using v4 is your solution I see...good idea overall :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not answer why the OP code is not working.

However, for anyone else experiencing the same issue, here is a different implementation which serves as a working solution.

```
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
    selectable: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    dateClick: function(info) {
      console.log(info.dateStr);
    },
    select: function(info) {
      console.log(info.startStr);
      console.log(info.endStr);
    }
  });
  calendar.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, I was checking wrong documentation version (I am using v3) which select function is implemented as follow:

```
select: function(startDate, endDate) {
      alert('selected ' + startDate.format() + ' to ' + endDate.format());
    }
```